# couchdb view not responding as expected

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have couchdb 0.10 installed on Ubuntu 10.04.
I have this view:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "transaction") {
    emit(doc.invoice_id, {id: doc._id, time: doc.time, user_id:doc.user_id});
  }
}
```

I call it through a get with key=247 parameter specified:

```
    http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/sfCouch/_view/find_by_invoice_id?key=247
```

In the db I have a document matching invoice_id = 247:

```
{
   "_id": "1357b381d8c22aa193f42de54e400d16",
   "_rev": "2-778ea588fa449851bbab6cfa9fa91bfa",
   "type": "transaction",
   "user_id": "1",
   "invoice_id": "247",
   "time": 1303895611.37
}
```

but no rows are given back from the view:

```
{"total_rows":4,"offset":1,"rows":[]}
```

this is my design document:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/sfCouch",
   "_rev": "11-95c82a9d562b3aa1470a02de943f49db",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "find_by_invoice_id": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\u000d\u000a  if (doc.type == \"transaction\") {\u000d\u000a    emit(doc.invoice_id, {id: doc._id, time: doc.time, user_id:doc.user_id});\u000d\u000a  }\u000d\u000a}"
       }
   }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post up the full design document? I suspect that you could perhaps have the format of the design document incorrect.

Comment: Any reason you can't upgrade to 1.0.2?

Answer (score 4):

As the key `invoice_id` is a string you need to specify the key as a JSON encoded string too.

Try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/sfCouch/_view/find_by_invoice_id?key=%22247%22
```

(the %22 is a URL Encoded " sign)

If that too fails can you post the output of:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/sfCouch/_view/find_by_invoice_id
```

Comment: This is the response with encoded ":
{"total_rows":4,"offset":3,"rows":[
{"id":"1357b381d8c22aa193f42de54e400d16","key":"247","value":{"id":"1357b381d8c22aa193f42de54e400d16","time":1303895611.37,"user_id":"1"}}
]}
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is! If you look that's the same id as the document you referenced.

Comment: If this was the solution that you used please could you mark the answer as "accepted"? Thanks!